# how to add items in menu slider

Tags: android, menu

I have a customviewadapter who is called in my main activity to build a menu slider.

My question is: How can I dinamycally add items to my object "dataList".

If I make this from CustomViewAdapter, when I finish the process to get places from google:

```
MainActivity prueba2 = new MainActivity();
            prueba2.onCreate(null);
```

It throws me an nullpointer exception

If I make this:

```
MainActivity prueba2 = new MainActivity();
prueba2.onPrepareOptionsMenu(null);
```

It throws me an error when I want to add some item like this part:

```
for(int i=0;i<s1.size();i++){


        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Sitios2", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
```

With a nullpointerexception too.

s1 gets the list of places but can´t add items to the menu in the first loop :(
I have to initialize the object? Use this getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);?

A little of help would be apreciated.

This is my CustomViewAdapter:

```
public class CustomDrawerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DrawerItem> {

    Context context;
    List<DrawerItem> drawerItemList;
    int layoutResID;
    public static String type;

    public CustomDrawerAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
            List<DrawerItem> listItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
        this.context = context;
        this.drawerItemList = listItems;
        this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;

    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        DrawerItemHolder drawerHolder;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            drawerHolder = new DrawerItemHolder();

            view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
            drawerHolder.ItemName = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.drawer_itemName);
            drawerHolder.icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawer_icon);

            drawerHolder.spinner = (Spinner) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.drawerSpinner);

            drawerHolder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerTitle);

            drawerHolder.headerLayout = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.headerLayout);
            drawerHolder.itemLayout = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.itemLayout);
            drawerHolder.spinnerLayout = (LinearLayout) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.spinnerLayout);

            view.setTag(drawerHolder);

        } else {
            drawerHolder = (DrawerItemHolder) view.getTag();

        }

        DrawerItem dItem = (DrawerItem) this.drawerItemList.get(position);

        if (dItem.isSpinner()) {
            drawerHolder.headerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
            drawerHolder.itemLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
            drawerHolder.spinnerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

            List<SpinnerItem> userList = new ArrayList<SpinnerItem>();

            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "Airport"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "ATM"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "Bank"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "Bus Station"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "church"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "doctor"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "Airport"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "hospital"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "mosque"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "movie Theate"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "hindu Temple"));
            userList.add(new SpinnerItem(R.drawable.user1, "restaurant"));



            CustomSpinnerAdapter adapter = new CustomSpinnerAdapter(context,
                    R.layout.custom_spinner_item, userList);
             final Double Lat2 = 25.751188242782035;
                final Double Lng2 = -100.3097140789032;
            drawerHolder.spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

            drawerHolder.spinner
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==0){

                            type = "airport";

                                // setPlaceTag puto = new setPlaceTag();
                            setPlaceTag.setChangedStat(true);

                                setPlaceTag.setTag(type);

                    //          MainActivity prueba = new MainActivity();
                        //      prueba.onPrepareOptionsMenu(null);
                                //set atm  string

                                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                                    sb.append("location="+Lat2+","+Lng2);
                                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                                    sb.append("&key=ba");

                                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();


                                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());

                                    }

                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==1){
                                String type = "atm";

                                setPlaceTag.tag = type;

                        //      MainActivity prueba = new MainActivity();
                            //  prueba.onPrepareOptionsMenu(null);
                                //set atm  string



                                  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
                                    sb.append("location="+Lat2+","+Lng2);
                                    sb.append("&radius=5000");
                                    sb.append("&types="+type);
                                    sb.append("&sensor=true");
                                    sb.append("&key=ba");

                                    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place json data 
                                    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();                                   

                                    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
                                    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());


                            //  Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   
                                    }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==2){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==3){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==4){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==5){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==6){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==7){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==8){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }

                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==9){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==10){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }
                            if(arg0.getSelectedItemPosition()==11){
                                Toast.makeText(context, "User Changed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   }




                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }
                    });

        } else if (dItem.getTitle() != null) {
            drawerHolder.headerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            drawerHolder.itemLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
            drawerHolder.spinnerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
            drawerHolder.title.setText(dItem.getTitle());
            Log.d("Getview","Passed4");
        } else {

            drawerHolder.headerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
            drawerHolder.spinnerLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
            drawerHolder.itemLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);

            drawerHolder.icon.setImageDrawable(view.getResources().getDrawable(
                    dItem.getImgResID()));
            drawerHolder.ItemName.setText(dItem.getItemName());
            Log.d("Getview","Passed5");
        }
        return view;
    }


    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);                


                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();                

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();                

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                        sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
                urlConnection.disconnect();
        }

        return data;
    }         


    /** A class, to download Google Places */
    private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        String data = null;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try{
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            }catch(Exception e){
                 Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result){            
            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Start parsing the Google places in JSON format
            // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
            parserTask.execute(result);
        }

    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String,String>>>{

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Invoked by execute() method of this object
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String,String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            List<HashMap<String, String>> places = null;            
            PlaceJSONParser placeJsonParser = new PlaceJSONParser();

            try{
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

                /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
                places = placeJsonParser.parse(jObject);

            }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }
            return places;
        }

        // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String,String>> list){            

            // Clears all the existing markers 
            // mMapView.clear();
//  notificacion(Results.toString());
                /* mMapView.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                          .position(new LatLng(Lat3,Lng3))
                          .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker1))
                          .title(Lugar)
                          .snippet(Desc));   
                */

    //      sendPlaces obj = new sendPlaces();
        //  obj.setList(list);



            setPlaceTag.List = list;

            MainActivity prueba2 = new MainActivity();
            prueba2.onCreate(null);

            //o = false;

              // Intent redirect = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
             //   context.startActivity(redirect);

//((Menu) map).clear();



            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            // Creating a marker
             //   MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

                // Getting a place from the places list
                HashMap<String, String> hmPlace = list.get(i);

                // Getting latitude of the place
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lat"));                

                // Getting longitude of the place
                double lng = Double.parseDouble(hmPlace.get("lng"));

                // Getting name
                String name = hmPlace.get("place_name");

                // Getting vicinity
                String vicinity = hmPlace.get("vicinity");

              //  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                // Setting the position for the marker
             //   markerOptions.position(latLng);

                // Setting the title for the marker. 
                //This will be displayed on taping the marker
               // markerOptions.title(name + " : " + vicinity);             

                // Placing a marker on the touched position
              //  mMapView.addMarker(markerOptions);            

            }       


        }

    }


    private static class DrawerItemHolder {
        TextView ItemName, title;
        ImageView icon;
        LinearLayout headerLayout, itemLayout, spinnerLayout;
        Spinner spinner;
    }
}
```

This is my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    CustomDrawerAdapter adapter;

    List<DrawerItem> dataList;

    public List<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    private boolean isChangedStat = false;
    private static final int MENUITEM = Menu.FIRST;
    private String wei;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializing
        dataList = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);


        // Add Drawer Item to dataList
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem(true)); // adding a spinner to the list

    //  list = 
        //for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){  //}

        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Closed sites")); // adding a header to the list
        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Sitios", R.drawable.ic_action_good));



        adapter = new CustomDrawerAdapter(this, R.layout.custom_drawer_item,
                dataList);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {


            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()



            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            if (dataList.get(0).isSpinner()
                    & dataList.get(1).getTitle() != null) {
                SelectItem(2);
            } else if (dataList.get(0).getTitle() != null) {
                SelectItem(1);
            } else {
                SelectItem(0);
            }
        }

        }



    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "wei estas en resume",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "vato estas en onpause",    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.




        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        //menu.clear();

    /*  String s = setPlaceTag.tag;



        Boolean check = setPlaceTag.isChangedStat;
        if(check.equals(true)){

        List<HashMap<String, String>> s1 = setPlaceTag.List;

    if(!s1.equals(null)){

        for(int i=0;i<s1.size();i++){


        dataList.add(new DrawerItem("Sitios2", R.drawable.ic_action_good));
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        }

    }   
        }    */

    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

    public void SelectItem(int possition) {

        Fragment fragment = null;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch (possition) {

        case 2:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
                    .get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
                    .get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 8:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
                    .get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
        case 9:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 10:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 11:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList
                    .get(possition).getImgResID());
            break;
        case 12:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 14:
            fragment = new FragmentThree();
            args.putString(FragmentThree.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentThree.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;  
        case 15:
            fragment = new FragmentOne();
            args.putString(FragmentOne.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentOne.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        case 16:
            fragment = new FragmentTwo();
            args.putString(FragmentTwo.ITEM_NAME, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getItemName());
            args.putInt(FragmentTwo.IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID, dataList.get(possition)
                    .getImgResID());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment) .commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(possition, true);
        setTitle(dataList.get(possition).getItemName());
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();


    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "estas en main activity modificando spinner",   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

        return false;
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            if (dataList.get(position).getTitle() == null) {
                SelectItem(position);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "diste click a sitios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     

        }
    }



}
```

Comment: I'd suggest trimming your code down to the minimal amount needed to answer the question, there is a lot of code here that you expect someone to debug.

Comment: I solve it with this: 

 adapter.clear();

dataList.add(new DrawerItem(name)); 

 mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

Many thanks!